# Cors error in nestjs. it is not working withCredentials

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am getting below error while using `"{withCredentials:true}"` in the `API` .if I am not using this then it is not working.

```
const submit = async(e:SyntheticEvent) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login',{
        email,
        password
    });
}
```

the above is working properly. When I am using `{withCredentials:true}` then it is giving `cors()` error.

```
const submit = async(e:SyntheticEvent) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login',{
        email,
        password
    },{withCredentials:true}); 
    setRedirect(true);
```

[image]

}

in `main.ts` file I have below configurations.

```
  const options = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.enableCors(options);
```

even I tried `credentials: false,` still it is not working.

I have to use `{withCredentials:true}` so that I can take `jwt tokens` for authorizations.

Comment: You cannot use both `credentials: true` and `origin: *`. See the note right above https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this.

```
  const options = {
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
  };
  app.enableCors(options);
```

Comment: Don't ever do this! You're allowing arbitrary origins with credentials; it pretty much voids the protection provided by the same-origin policy. This is terrible advice in terms of security.

Comment: Sure...I thought it is for learning ,so I recommended